# Is there a reason behind the ordering of letters in the English alphabet?

Tags: alphabet, sort-ordering

Is there a reason behind the ordering of letters in the English alphabet? i.e. why are we taught “A,B,C,D,E,F,...,Z”? Why not “L,A,S,U,I,Z,...,C”?

I am asking this because, in some of the languages I know, I am told that the ordering of the letters in the alphabet is based on the ease with which they can be pronounced or the frequency with which they are used or depending on the part of the vocal cord that needs to be stressed to pronounce the letter.

Is there a similar rationale?

**EDIT**

You can see a couple of references for arrangement of letters in Sanskrit [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MeqtYsnoLKwC&pg=PR16&lpg=PR16&dq=ordering+of+alphabet+in+sanskrit&source=bl&ots=UZLAVEcM0C&sig=nCxoOvdcWhbP3cCBwySghqTSVJg&hl=en&ei=OGc6TbKxJoeusAPajvyEAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=arranged&f=false) and [here](http://acharya.iitm.ac.in/sanskrit/sans.php?lnum=0&pnum=4).

Comment: @Jasper Loy: Only one *English* alphabet. :)

Comment: @Jasper: Edited... Hope it is correct now. If not feel free to edit it.

Comment: @Sivaram: what are the languages for which you heard that the ordering of the alphabet is logical?

Comment: @PLL: I have heard that in Sanskrit the ordering is based on how we pronounce the letters. You might want to look at these websites http://books.google.com/books?id=MeqtYsnoLKwC&pg=PR16&lpg=PR16&dq=ordering+of+alphabet+in+sanskrit&source=bl&ots=UZLAVEcM0C&sig=nCxoOvdcWhbP3cCBwySghqTSVJg&hl=en&ei=OGc6TbKxJoeusAPajvyEAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=arranged&f=false    http://acharya.iitm.ac.in/sanskrit/sans.php?lnum=0&pnum=4

Comment: +1 Good question in fact. The history on this is no clear.

Comment: @Sivaram: That's interesting. Devanagari and other Sanskrit/Indian scripts are of course derived from Phoenician and ultimately Egyption hieroglyphs, as are all European scripts. This perhaps suggests that the ordering of the Latin alphabet appeared after the Phoenician stage (the latest common ancestor), perhaps at the Greek stage?

Comment: @Noldorin: I am not aware of the origins of Sanskrit or Devanagari. Could you show me some pointers as to why you believe they are derived from Phoenician and ultimately Egyption hieroglyphs? If I am not wrong, the mature period of the Indus Valley civilization was actually before the mature period of the Egyptian civilization and the language they spoke was called Harappan language (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harappan_language). So I am more intended to believe that Sanskrit/Indian scripts are derived from this Harappan language.

Comment: @Sivaram: The Indian (in particular Indus Valley) civilisation is no doubt very old, but it is widely agreed by academics that the Egyptian is significantly older. The Harappan civilisation used the "Indus script", which no-one has yet deciphered, but it is not considered an alphabet generally. Culturally and linguistically India underwent major changes with the beginning of the Aryan civilisation (~2000 BC). They brought with them the Phoenician script (a real alphabet), from which *all subsequent* scripts in India are derived. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari ("parent systems").

Comment: Also, note that academics believe only *three* writing systems were developed in the history of humanity. The first, Sumerian, is now extinct. The second, Egyptian, gave rise to the Phoenician alphabet and later Greek, Latin, Indian scripts, and many others. The third was Chinese, from which modern Chinese and other SE Asian scripts are derived. The "Harappan script" is a contentious fourth script (or third, in chronology). Some think it is ultimatley derived from Egyptian, but others thing it is independent - it's not yet proven.

Comment: @Noldorin (comment about the ordering possibly having appeared after the Phoenician stage): not necessarily. The Arabic alphabet derives from the Phoenician too, but is reordered according to the shapes of the glyphs (except for when it's used for numeration like the Greek and Hebrew alphabets). Devanagari could have been reordered in the same way.

Comment: @Alex: Oh of course, I just said *possibly*. It is *more likely* that it appeared at the post-Phoenician stage, which I think is a fair comment.

Comment: @Noldorin: Interesting that there have been only 3 or 4 origins of writing systems; I guess I always subconsciously assumed several systems in ancient Asia, but apparently not. Note that my Wikipedia quote seems quite convinced that modern ordering already existed (partly) in the Ugaritic alphabet, which is older than the Phoenician one.

Comment: @Cerberus: Indeed, the alphabet really spread via the Middle-East from a single source (Egypt). Regarding Ugaritic, it is also derived from Egyptian - as are all Semitic alphabets (including Phoenician). The theory is that the Semitic peoples learnt how to read and write after having been ruled by/come in contact with Egypt. Phoenician became the dominant one however, as the others disappeared, since it was the greatest political power in the region for a long time.

Comment: @Noldorin: Wikipedia agrees; but why did you think that our ordering was post-Phoenician? According to Wikipedia, it is already evident from those pre-Phoenician, Ugaritic texts.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yeah, so I wasn't quite accurate. I meant post-Egyptian times really (i.e. any time *after* the alphabet left Egypt). Phoenician and Ugaritic alphabets are only separated by a few centuries, and the former closely derives from the latter.

Comment: @Noldorin: Ah OK, then we are agreed.

Comment: It's funny - there are at least two 'English' alphabets; the UK English one (the definitive English English alphabet?) that has zed as its twenty-sixth letter, and the US English (American alphabet?) that has zee as its twenty-sixth letter.

Comment: I can just imagine the UK version of the alphabet song: "A bed ced ded ee ef ged... double-you, ex, why, and zed. Now I know my A-Bed-Ced, next time won't you sing with med!" :)

Comment: @Alex: The UK version (well, the version we learnt in India) ends with "ex wye zed, sugar on your bread; if you don't like it, better go to bed. Next Sunday morning, come to me; I will teach you ay-bee-see." Etc.

Comment: I wanted to say "They were put in alphabetical order...of course" but I could hear the groans in my own head.

Comment: @Cerberus Done. Sorry. It was while I visited english.stackexchange.

Comment: @Noldorin: What about Mayan?

Comment: @Mitch: Indeed, I should have said "Old World" writing systems, since these are by far the most extensive, well-documented, and most intensively studied historically. However it seems like several independent writing systems (logographic as far as I can tell) developed in Mesoamerica, independent of Old World systems. Whether all they can be traced back to a single Mesoamerican common ancestor, I do not know (quite possibly even scholars are not sure yet).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The ABC order already existed in some form [about 1400 BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet#Letter_names_and_sequence_of_some_alphabets), in the Ugaritic script, from which our alphabet is descended. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet#Alphabetical_order):

> It is unknown whether the earliest
>   alphabets had a defined sequence. Some
>   alphabets today, such as the Hanuno'o
>   script, are learned one letter at a
>   time, in no particular order, and are
>   not used for collation where a
>   definite order is required. **However, a
>   dozen [Ugaritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugaritic_alphabet#Abecedaries) tablets from the
>   fourteenth century BCE preserve the
>   alphabet in two sequences. One, the
>   ABCDE order later used in Phoenician,
>   has continued with minor changes in
>   Hebrew, Greek, Armenian, Gothic,
>   Cyrillic, and Latin;** the other, HMĦLQ,
>   was used in southern Arabia and is
>   preserved today in Ethiopic.[16] Both
>   orders have therefore been stable for
>   at least 3000 years.

The English alphabet comes from the Latin alphabet (it is even often still called the Latin alphabet), which in turn comes from the Greek alphabet. All modern alphabets are most probably in some way descended from the [Proto-Sinaitic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Sinaitic_alphabet), which probably originated around 2100-1800 BC, but whose ordering is unknown. The Greek alphabet developed from Proto-Sinaitic through Phoenician. Many times in between Proto-Sinaitic and English, letters have been added and removed. W, U, and J are among the most recent additions, which did not exist in classical Latin.

The first letters or proto-letters were taken by the Proto-Sinaitic alphabet from non-alphabetic Egyptian hieroglyphs, which were mostly ideograms, small depictions of objects. Note that these hieroglyphs were used in an entirely different way—the Egyptians didn't use them as alphabetical letters—, and so the order in Egyptian doesn't tell us much about the order in alphabets. Perhaps there was a logical sequence in those earliest forms, but that is unknown; it might very well be an arbitrary order.
For all practical purposes, the modern order is best considered meaningless, though fixed.

Note that the Arabic script is also descended from Phoenician, and its alphabet uses the same order similar to our own.

Comment: The Greek alphabet in turn derives from the Phoenician alphabet, which in turns derives from Egyptian hieroglyphs. I'd be curious when order first appeared...

Comment: Note that while the source of the ordering may be historically arbitrary, the current order is now significant in an era of computers, code-based representation of text, and the need to 'sort' words and phrases.

Comment: @Cerberus: Your history on the Egyptian alphabet is slightly misinformed I think. The late form of Egyptian hieroglyphs (they actually had two writing systems) *do* represent an alphabet (alongside logographs), so the Egyptians (and not the Proto-Sinaitic peoples), should be credited with invention of the alphabet. The rest of your post is very good. :)

Comment: Also, note that a similar thing happened with numerals. In the West we often credit the Arabs with developing the numerals 0 - 9 and their uses in the denary system. In fact, the ancient Hindus invented this system, while the Arabs just transported it to us (in a slightly altered form). Similarly, the Semites transported the *Egyptian invention of the alphabet* to the rest of the world, altering it in the process.

Comment: @Noldorin: But I read that, while the Egyptians used hieroglyphs for some alphabetic functions, this usage died out, and it was in no way related to the Proto-Sinaitic alphabet's use of the hieroglyphs. I only read this on Wikipedia; I don't know a lot about the Egyptian semi-alphabet myself.

Comment: @Noldorin: I found my source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet#Predecessors - Do you think the Wiki article presents it wrong? I couldn't say.

Comment: @Cerberus: Geographically, they are very close neighbours. It is very hard to believe the Egyptian alphabet did not influence the Semitic one. In fact, it states "The first purely alphabetic script is thought to have been developed around 1850 BCE for Semitic workers". This suggests that the Egyptians actually took their own alphabet and applied it to the language of the Semitic slaves they ruled! Interesting. In any case, I give all credit to the Egyptians.

Comment: Aha. [This page](http://www.citrinitas.com/history_of_viscom/alphabet.html) clarifies things. Evidently, since the Semitic workers did not in general know how to speak Ancient Egyptian, they used their own language. The Ancient Egyptians however wanted to record their language directly, so developed an alphabetic script for their use (based on their own much older proto-alphabetic system).

Comment: So in summary, it's just an arbitrary order carried over from history; there's no rationale.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: There isn't any as far as we know... but what if there once was one? The letters were of course not pronounced the same way as they are in our version of the alphabet, in which the order makes no sense.

Comment: Rationales developed later. When literacy became a proxy for wisdom, and wisdom for magic, "grammar" generated words like _grammarye_ and _grimoire_, with the magic word _abracadabra_, followed by _efragahefra_, which are just alphabetic mnemonics. Much easier than astrology.

Answer (score 9):

The ancient Greek [Ionian numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionian_numerals) used the position of a letter in the Greek alphabet for its value, i.e. αʹ = 1, βʹ = 2, γʹ = 3, etc.

This is evidence Greek letters had a fixed sequence as of the 4th century BC. As @Cerberus pointed out, the sequence was carried into the Latin, and hence English, alphabet.

Comment: Interesting! So the ordering goes back at least as far as Ancient Greek times.

Comment: @Noldorin: It goes back at least as far as the Ugaritic alphabets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugaritic_alphabet#Abecedaries

Comment: Note that Greek also had another, older numeral system, still in use in the classical era, in which each digit was represented by the first letter of its Greek name: the pi for penta (5), the delta for de(u)ka (10), eta (100), chi (1000), mu (10,000); then they made 50 by putting a small delta inside a pi, etc; the number 5073 would be: pi(chi) pi(delta) delta delta |||. The number 1 was a vertical line, as in most languages.

Comment: Every language that used the variants of the Ox-House-Camel-Door version of the Semitic alphabet used the alphabetic order to represent numbers. The Romans did too, but theirs were specialized letters with specialized meanings not depending on alphabetic order. After all, they were engineers, even if they did have to use Roman numerals (think about that).

Answer (score 1):

Egyptian hieroglyphs were narrowed down to less than 30-ish, and other people like the Greeks narrowed it down even further as they did not use some letters. Z used to be next to G (or instead of), so when it was re-added it was added to the end. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_value) may be of interest.

Comment: G is just C with a line added; I have no idea why it was placed alphabetically where it was; you would think the Romans would have placed it next to C or K.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, there does seem to be some logic and planning behind the distribution of the vowels. Whether the consonants also show any planning in their distribution is not quite so clear, though I think there are signs of intentional regularity and grouping of the consonants.

Firstly, the vowels occur at almost regular intervals:

***A***  BCD  ***E***  FGH  ***I***  JKLMN  ***O***  PQRST  ***U***  XYZ

The regularity becomes more evident if we write the alphabet as the Romans wrote it. They had no J or K; they wrote V, not U; they had no W; and I think they had no X, Y or Z. Thus:

***A***  BCD  ***E***  FGH  ***I***  LMN  ***O***  PQRST  ***V***

They used V for a sound that was sometimes "oo" and sometimes "w", so to them V was a vowel. All the other vowels are separated by 3 consonants; maybe they put the vowel V at the end instead of after R so that the alphabet began and ended with a vowel?

Secondly, there seems to be some intentional logic in the *order* of those vowels (A  E  I  O  U), when pronounced as the Romans did, and as most European languages still pronounce them: it follows at least approximately a circuit around the mouth. The vowels are partly defined by where the forward hump of the tongue is. Roman A had the hump of the tongue drawn back and low down; Roman E had the hump forward and medium high; Roman I had the hump about as far forward and high as it could go; Roman O and V (the latter pronounced oo) had the hump further back, but I am a bit vague about how far back and how high or low.

Thirdly, I think there are some weak signs of planning in the order and grouping of the consonants.
BC (the C being pronounced /k/, not /s/ in Roman times) compares with FG: B is a bilabial *plosive*, F has at times been pronounced as bilabial *approximant*, meaning it has at least sometimes been pronounced by simply blowing through slightly parted lips. (In fact this is how Dr Johnson in his 1755 Dictionary of the English Language describes the pronunciation of F in the English of his day!!). C is a *voiceless* velar plosive, G (in the Roman /g/ pronunciation as in the English word "get") is a *voiced* velar plosive. How D might be compared to H I do not know. Then L, M and N are all voiced sounds that can be pronounced continuously with no sound change. (I do not know how a linguist would express that ...) Finally, P, Q, R, S and T may just be a collection of left-over consonants. The appearance of logic in the arrangement of the consonants seems decidedly less convincing to me than for the vowels, but that may be due to the difficulty of arranging consonants in any kind of order, especially before the days of X-rays, since no one could see inside anyone's mouth to be sure what was going on.

Comment: What an interesting answer! The part about the pattern in where the different vowel sounds are produced really stands out as more than just coincidence. By the way, I'm pretty sure the term for 'continuous' consonants like "L," "M" and "N" is *sonorants*.