# Where does alphabetical order come from?

Tags: alphabet, sort-ordering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a reason behind the ordering of letters in the English alphabet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9587/is-there-a-reason-behind-the-ordering-of-letters-in-the-english-alphabet)

Alphabetical order seems something obvious, we do not usually ask ourselves if it is the best possible one, why it is this way, and most of all what is its origin. As the title says, what is the historical origin of the alphabetical order?