# Why is letter "z" the last letter of alphabet?

Tags: alphabet

it's been on my mind for sometime, why is Z last letter of alphabet, why is A the first, why is D the 4th letter, are these letters just based randomly then people agreed on them, therefore creating the "alphabetic order" or were they based on something more logical, scientific, such as syllable and the way each are pronounced.

Comment: Without Googling, I'm guessing it probably has something to do with the Greek and/or  Latin alphabet. They're older languages too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z *In earlier times, the English alphabets used by children terminated not with Z but with & or related typographic symbols. In her 1859 novel "Adam Bede", George Eliot refers to Z being followed by & when her character Jacob Storey says, "He thought it [Z] had only been put to finish off th' alphabet like; though ampusand would ha' done as well, for what he could see."*

Comment: History of the alphabet https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet

Comment: The general question is answered here: [Is there a reason behind the ordering of letters in the English alphabet?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9587/is-there-a-reason-behind-the-ordering-of-letters-in-the-english-alphabet) For Z, which was a more recent addition to the Latin alphabet than the other letters, the reason it comes last is because it wasn't used in native Latin words, but only in Greek loans into Latin. Its old place in the alphabet had been taken by G, which was a new letter created for Latin as a variant of C.